# Convert json string data back into python image object

Tags: python, django

The code below get's image data from a form, and then converts so it can be json serializable.

I want to show the image on the html template by converting the image data into base64, however i need to convert the json data (string) back into a python image object / data.

**View**

```
def View1(request):

    form = FormFile(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            image = request.FILES.get('image').read()
            request.session['image_file'] = json.dumps(str(image))

            return redirect('View2')

    template = 'view1.html'
    context = {
         'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

def View2(request):

    img = request.session.get('image_file') # this is the json data that needs to be converted back into python image object

    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile()
    img_temp.write(img)
    img_temp.flush()

    img = Image.open(img_temp)
    img_format = img.format
    img.close()

    with open(img , "rb") as imageFile:
        encode_image = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

    form = FormCreate(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
             instance = form.save(commit=False)
             instance.image.save(img_format , File(img_temp), save = True)
             instance.save()

    template = 'view2.html'
    context = {
         'encode_image': encode_image,
         'img_format': img_format,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**Template (View1)**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.image }} # form image input
</form>
```

**Template (View2)**

```
<img src="data:image/{{ img_format }};base64, {{ encode_image }}"></img>
```

**Image String**

```
"b'\\x89PNG\\r\\n\\x1a\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00\\rIHDR\\x00\\x00\\x01\\\\\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x8f\\x08\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x10\\xbch\\xad\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x06bKGD\\x00\\xff\\x00\\xff\
\x00\\xff\\xa0\\xbd\\xa7\\x93\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x07tIME\\x07\\xd7\\x06\\r\\x17&\\x1e\\x9e}\\xa0\\xf8\\x00\\x00\\x10\\xb9IDATx\\x9c\\xed\\xdd{\\xcc\\xf7w]\\xdf\\xf1\\xe7\\xdd\
\x03\\xa5\\xa5\\xe7r*TN\\xf6d+\\x95\\x83\\xb6\\xea\\x80t\\xe0\\xe6\\xd4@q\\x9b\\x91\\xb90\\xdc\\xcc\\x8c.K\\xa6\\xe2\\xcc\\xb6lY\\xb6\\xc5\\xcd\\x1d4&\\x16\\xa2\\x8bl\\x98\
\x99\\xe9p\\x91\\r\\xc9P\\x91\\xc3\\xaa\"\\x1d-t\\x90\\x01\\xc5:(\\xd0\\x16ZJ\\xcfGz\\xd8\\x1f\\xdf\\xab+w{\\x1f\\xae\\xeb\\xba\\xaf\\xdf\\xef\\xf3\\xfb\\xfd\\xbe\\x8fG\\xf
2\\xceu\\xffu\\xe7\\x95\\xebw}_\\xd7\\xe7\\xfa|O\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x0
0\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\
\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x
00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x1c\\xce\\xbe\\xd1\\x01\\xe00N\\xa9\\x8e\\x
afN\\xa8N\\xed\\xc0?\\xb3_\\xab\\xee\\xaan\\xaf\\xee\\xa8\\x1eYZ:\\xd8\\x01\\x85\\xcb(\\xcf\\xa8\\xce\\xad\\xce\\xa9\\xbe\\xa1zfu\\xd6\\xd6\\xd73\\xb7\\xbe>m\\x97\\xff\\xf7
=\\xd5\\x9d\\xd5\\xad\\xd5\\xe7\\xab/U_\\xa8n\\xac\\xbeX}\\xba\\xba\\xbezx\\xf7\\xf1a\\xe7\\x14.\\x8bvZ\\xf5\\xf2\\xad\\xb9\\xa8:\\xbb\\xa9hO\\x1d\\x19\\xaaz\\xa0\\xfaLS\\x
f9^[}\\xac\\xfaHS1\\xc3B(\\\\\\xf6\\xd21M\\xc5\\xfa\\xaa\\xea\\xdb\\xb6\\xfe\\xfd\\xa2\\xa1\\x89v\\xee\\xcbM\\xc5{U\\xf5\\xc7\\xd5\\x87\\xaa{\\x87&bc(\\\\\\x8e\\xc4\\xd1\\x
d5\\xcb\\xaaK\\xb7\\xe6\\x95\\xd5I\\x03\\xf3,\\xc2\\x03\\xd5\\x87\\xab\\xf7o\\xcd\\x95M{\\xc6\\x00\\x0bwB\\xf5\\xfa\\xeam\\xd5\\xcd\\xd5\\xa33\\x9b;\\xaa\\xdf\\xac\\xde\\xd
0tB\\x0f`O\\x9dR\\xbd\\xa9zW\\xd3\\x9f\\xd7\\xa3KoU\\xe6\\x81\\xea\\xf7\\xaa\\x1f\\xabN\\xdf\\xf5w\\x17\\x98\\xbdc\\xab\\xef\\xad~#%\\xbb\\x9d\\xb9\\xbfzg\\xd3\\xea\\xff\\x
b8]|\\xbf\\x81\\x19:\\xaf\\xfa\\x85\\xa6\\x93G\\xa3Kl]\\xe7\\xd6\\xea\\x97\\xaa\\x0bw\\xf8\\xbd\\x07f\\xe0\\xe8\\xea\\xb2\\xea\\xf7\\x9bn\\x1a\\x18]X\\x9b4\\xef\\xaf\\xfeJ\
\xd3\\x15\\x1c\\xc0\\x8c\\x9d\\\\\\xfdL\\xf5\\xd9\\xc6\\x17\\xd3\\xa6\\xcf\\x17\\xaa\\x7f\\x98\\x13m0;gT\\xff\\xa2\\xba\\xad\\xf1E4\\xb7\\xb9\\xbd\\xfa\\xd9\\xa6;\\xe9\\x80
\\rvf\\xf5\\xf3\\xd5\\xdd\\x8d/\\x9e\\xb9\\xcf=\\xd5/6\\xdd\\xce\\x0cl\\x90S\\xab\\x9f\\xcb\\xd5\\x06\\xab8\\xf7n}6\\xa3ou\\x06\\x8e\\xd0S\\xaa7W\\xb74\\xbeX\\xcc\\xa1\\xe7
\\xab\\xd5O7=\\x19\\rX3o\\xa8>\\xd7\\xf8\"1;\\x9b\\xeb\\xb7>;`\\r\\x9c_\\xbd\\xaf\\xf1\\xc5a\\x8el\\xdeW]\\x10\\xb0\\x92\\x8e\\xaf\\xfee\\xd3\\xed\\xa6\\xa3\\xcb\\xc2\\xec\
\xcd<P\\xfd\\xeb\\xea\\xc4\\x80\\x95\\xf1\\x17r-\\xed&\\xcf\\xf5[\\x9f10\\xd0\\xd3\\xaa\\xb7\\xe6\\xee\\xb09\\xcc#\\xd5\\xaf\\xb4y\\x8f\\xbf\\x84\\xb5\\xf0\\xaa\\xea\\xba\\
xc6\\x17\\x81Y\\xee|\\xaezM\\xc0R\\x1c[\\xfd\\xbb\\xa6\\xf7q\\x8d>\\xf8\\xcd\\x98y\\xa4\\xe9\\x06\\x96c\\x03\\x16\\xe6y\\xd5\\x9f4\\xfe\\x807\\xab1WV/\\x0c\\xd8s\\xdfW}\\xa
5\\xf1\\x07\\xb9Y\\xad\\xb9\\xad\\xfa\\x81\\x80=qt\\xd3\\xad\\x9fN\\x8c\\x99C\\xcd/\\xe6\\x11\\x90pDN\\xa9~\\xb7\\xf1\\x07\\xb3Y\\x8fyo^\\xf5\\x03\\xbbrv\\xf5\\xa9\\xc6\\x1
f\\xc4f\\xbd\\xe6\\xba\\xdc\\xa1\\x06;\\xf2\\xea\\xa6\\xd7\\xb4\\x8c>x\\xcdz\\xce\\x9dM{\\xfe\\xc0a\\xbc\\xb1z\\xb0\\xf1\\x07\\xadY\\xefy\\xa8\\xfa\\x91X)G\\x8f\\x0e\\xc0~~
\\xa2\\xfa\\xe5|.\\x1c\\xb9\\xa3\\xaa\\xd76]\\xaf}\\xc5\\xe0,\\xb0R\\xf65\\xbdve\\xf4\\xaa\\xc8l\\xe6\\xbc%\\xbf\\xc4\\xa1\\x9a\\x0e\\x84_i\\xfcAi6{~#\\xa5\\xcb\\xcc\\x1dU\
\xfd\\x87\\xc6\\x1f\\x8cf\\x1e\\xf3\\x8e\\\\\\xab\\xcbL\\xed\\xab\\xde\\xd6\\xf8\\x83\\xd0\\xcck~+\\xcf``f\\xf6U\\xbf\\xda\\xf8\\x83\\xcf\\xccs\\xfek\\xd3\\xfb\\xee`\\x16.o
\\xfcAg\\xe6=\\xbf\\xde\\xf4\\x8b\\x9f%\\xb2\\x89\\xbe|\\xff\\xac\\xfa\\xfb\\xa3C0{\\x175\\xdd\\x06\\xfc\\x9e\\xd1A\\xe6D\\xe1.\\xd7\\x8fW\\xffft\\x08\\xd8rI\\xd3{\\xd3\\xf
eht\\x90\\xb9P\\xb8\\xcb\\xf3\\xba\\xea\\xd7\\x9a\\xaeL\\x80U\\xf1]\\xd5\\xcd\\xd5U\\xa3\\x83\\xcc\\x81=\\x9c\\xe5\\xb8\\xa4z\\x7fu\\xc2\\xe8 p\\x00\\x0fW\\xdf\\xd3\\xf4\\x
b41\\x16H\\xe1.\\xdeYM\\xab\\x87g\\x8d\\x0e\\x02\\x87pG\\xd3\\xc2\\xe0\\xda\\xd1A6\\x99?o\\x17\\xeb\\x84\\xea\\x9d)[V\\xdf)\\xd5\\xbb\\xab\\xd3F\\x07\\xd9d\\nwq\\x1e\\xbb\\
xd6\\xf6[G\\x07\\x81m:\\xbb\\xe9\\x1a]w\\xa3-\\x88\\x93f\\x8b\\xf3\\xd3\\xd5O\\x8d\\x0e\\x01;\\xf4\\xc2\\xa6\\xbf\\xcc\\xec\\xe7.\\x80=\\xdc\\xc5xE\\xf5\\x81\\xac\\x14XO\\x
8fV\\x97U\\xbf3:\\xc8\\xa6Q\\xb8{\\xef\\xf4\\xeacM\\xaf4\\x87u\\xf5\\xd5\\xeae\\xd5\\xf5\\xa3\\x83l\\x12{\\xb8{k_\\xf5\\xf6\\x94-\\xeb\\xef\\xf4\\xea7\\xf3\\xcc\\x85=e\\x0f
wo\\xfd\\xbd\\xad\\x81MpVS\\xe1\\xfe\\xc1\\xe8 \\x9b\\xc2\\x96\\xc2\\xde\\xb9\\xb0\\xe9z\\xdb\\xa7\\x8e\\x0e\\x02{\\xe8\\xe1\\xeaU\\xd5\\x87F\\x07\\xd9\\x04\\nwo\\x1c\\xdd\
\xf4\\x03y\\xf1\\xe8 \\xb0\\x00\\x7fZ\\xbd\\xb4\\xbagt\\x90ugKao\\xfc\\x83\\xeao\\x8c\\x0e\\x01\\x0brFuR\\x9e,v\\xc4\\xacp\\x8f\\xdc\\x85\\xd5\\xd5\\xd5q\\xa3\\x83\\xc0\\x0
2=Z\\xbd\\xa6\\xe9rGvI\\xe1\\x1e\\x99\\xa3\\x9a\\xb6\\x12.\\x19\\x1d\\x04\\x96\\xe03M\\xcf\\xd1}`t\\x90ueK\\xe1\\xc8\\xfc\\xed\\xea\\xc7F\\x87\\x80%9\\xa3\\xa9l\\xaf\\x18\\
x1dd]Y\\xe1\\xee\\xde\\x19MOV:ct\\x10X\\xa2\\xfb\\xab\\x0b\\xaa\\xcf\\x8e\\x0e\\xb2\\x8e\\xdc\\xf8\\xb0{\\xff*e\\xcb\\xfc<\\xb5\\xfa\\xa5\\xd1!\\xd6\\x95\\x15\\xee\\xee\\\\
\\xd2\\xb4w\\xeb\\x17\\x16suY\\xf5\\xae\\xd1!\\xd6\\x8d\\xc2\\xdd\\x9d?lz@\\r\\xcc\\xd5\\'\\xabo\\xa9\\x1e\\x1a\\x1dd\\x9dX\\xa1\\xed\\xdc\\xebR\\xb6pA\\xf5\\xc3\\xa3C\\xac
\\x1b+\\xdc\\x9d9\\xba\\xfax\\xd3\\x0f\\x1b\\xcc\\xdd\\x8d\\xd59\\xd5\\xbd\\xa3\\x83\\xac\\x0b+\\xdc\\x9dyS\\xca\\x16\\x1e\\xf3\\x9c<d\\x7fG\\xacp\\xb7\\xef\\xb8\\xa6{\\xca
\\xbfat\\x10X!wT/\\xa8n\\x1f\\x9cc-X\\xe1n\\xdf\\xdfL\\xd9\\xc2\\x13\\x9dR\\xfd\\xdd\\xd1!\\xd6\\x85\\x15\\xee\\xf6\\x1c\\xd3t\\x93\\xc3\\x8bF\\x07\\x81\\x15\\xf4\\x95\\xa6
w\\xa1\\xdd=:\\xc8\\xaa\\xb3\\xc2\\xdd\\x9e7\\xa4l\\xe1`\\x9e^\\xfd\\xe8\\xe8\\x10\\xeb\\xc0\\n\\xf7\\xf0\\x8ej\\xba2\\xe1\\xc2\\xd1A`\\x85\\xdd\\xd4\\xb4(\\xb9\\x7ft\\x90U
f\\x85{x\\xafM\\xd9\\xc2\\xe1\\x9cY\\xfd\\xd0\\xe8\\x10\\xabN\\xe1\\x1e\\x9e\\x13\\x02\\xb0=\\x8e\\x95\\xc3\\xb0\\xa5ph\\xdfT\\xfd\\x9f|\\x9f`\\xbb\\xbe\\xb3\\xfa\\x93\\xd1
!V\\x95\\x15\\xee\\xa1\\xfdx\\xca\\x16v\\xc2*\\xf7\\x10\\x94\\xc9\\xc1\\x9dX\\xddP\\x9d<:\\x08\\xac\\x91\\x07\\x9bn\\x84\\xb8ip\\x8e\\x95d\\x85{p\\x7f=e\\x0b;\\xf5\\x94\\xb
cP\\xf5\\xa0\\x14\\xee\\xc1\\xf9\\xa1\\x81\\xddq\\xec\\x1c\\x84-\\x85\\x03\\xfb\\xc6\\xa6\\xe7&\\xf8\\xfe\\xc0\\xee\\xbc\\xbc\\xfa\\xe8\\xe8\\x10\\xab\\xc6\\n\\xf7\\xc0\\xd
e\\x98\\xb2\\x85#\\xf1\\xc6\\xd1\\x01V\\x91Ry\\xb2}M\\xab\\xdbo\\x1c\\x1d\\x04\\xd6\\xd8\\x97\\xab\\xb3\\xf2F\\x88\\xfdX\\xe1>\\xd9\\xc5)[8R\\xcf\\xaa^=:\\xc4\\xaaQ\\xb8O\\
xf6\\xfd\\xa3\\x03\\xc0\\x86x\\xfd\\xe8\\x00\\xab\\xc6\\x96\\xc2\\x93}\\xaa:\\x7ft\\x08\\xd8\\x0074=C\\xfa\\xd1\\xd1AV\\x85\\x15\\xee\\xfe\\xceO\\xd9\\xc2^yn\\xf5\\xb2\\xd1
!V\\x89\\xc2\\xdd\\xdfe\\xa3\\x03\\xc0\\x86qL}\\x1d\\x85\\xbb\\xbf\\xd7\\x8e\\x0e\\x00\\x1b\\xe6u\\xa3\\x03\\xac\\x12{\\xb8\\x8f;\\xa9\\xfaj\\xd3\\xebt\\x80\\xbd\\xf1h\\xf5
\\xec\\xea\\xe6\\xd1AV\\x81\\x15\\xee\\xe3^\\x99\\xb2\\x85\\xbd\\xb6\\xaf\\xbatt\\x88U\\xa1p\\x1f\\xe7\\x9aAX\\x8cKG\\x07X\\x15\\n\\xf7q\\xaf\\x19\\x1d\\x006\\xd4\\xa5\\xa3
\\x03\\xac\\n{\\xb8\\x93\\xd3\\xab[\\xf2\\x0b\\x08\\x16\\xe5\\xcc\\xeaK\\xa3C\\x8c\\xa6`&\\x17\\xe7{\\x01\\x8b\\xf4\\x8a\\xd1\\x01V\\x81\\x92\\x99\\\\<:\\x00l\\xb8\\x97\\x8
f\\x0e\\xb0\\n\\x14\\xee\\xc4\\x0f\\x03,\\x96c,{\\xb8\\x8f\\xb9\\xa9\\xe9ZA`1n\\xad\\x9e>:\\xc4hV\\xb8\\xd33;\\x95-,\\xd6\\x19\\xd5\\x8bF\\x87\\x18M\\xe1\\xd6E\\xa3\\x03\\x
c0L\\xbctt\\x80\\xd1\\x14\\xae\\xa7\\x83\\xc1\\xb2\\\\8:\\xc0h\\n\\xb7\\xce\\x1b\\x1d\\x00f\\xe2\\xdc\\xd1\\x01FS\\xb8\\xf5M\\xa3\\x03\\xc0L\\x9c3:\\xc0h\\n\\xd7\\n\\x17\\x
96e\\xf6+\\xdc\\xb9_\\x16vJu\\xfb\\xe8\\x100#\\xcfl\\xba\\x8d~\\x96\\xe6\\xbe\\xc2=kt\\x00\\x98\\x99\\xb3G\\x07\\x18i\\xee\\x85\\xfb\\xdc\\xd1\\x01`f\\x9e3:\\xc0H\\n\\x17X\
\xa6Y\\xdfd\\xa4p\\x81eR\\xb83\\xa6pa\\xb9l)\\xcc\\xd8\\xe9\\xa3\\x03\\xc0\\xccX\\xe1\\xce\\xd8\\xc9\\xa3\\x03\\xc0\\xcc\\xccz\\x91\\xa3p\\x81ez\\xda\\xe8\\x00#)\\\\`\\x99N
\\x19\\x1d`$\\x85\\x0b,\\xd3\\t\\xa3\\x03\\x8c4\\xf7\\xc2\\x9d\\xf5o[\\x18\\xc0\\x96\\x02\\xc0\\x92\\x1c?:\\xc0H\\n\\x17`I\\x14.\\xc0\\x92(\\\\\\x80%Q\\xb8\\x00K2\\xf7\\xc2
}dt\\x00`>\\xe6^\\xb8w\\x8d\\x0e\\x003\\xf3\\xe0\\xe8\\x00#)\\\\`\\x99\\xee\\x1c\\x1d`\\xa4\\xb9\\x17\\xee\\xbd\\xa3\\x03\\xc0\\xcc(\\xdc\\x19\\xbbgt\\x00\\x98\\x19\\x85;cw
\\x8c\\x0e\\x003\\xa3pg\\xec\\xe6\\xd1\\x01`ff\\xbd\\xc8\\x99{\\xe1\\xde4:\\x00\\xcc\\xcc\\xac\\x179s/\\xdc/\\x8d\\x0e\\x003\\xf3\\xc5\\xd1\\x01FR\\xb8\\xc02\\xdd0:\\xc0Hs/
\\xdcY\\x7f\\xf80\\xc0\\xac\\x8f9\\x85\\x0b,\\xd3\\x8d\\xa3\\x03\\x8c\\xb4ot\\x80\\x15pWu\\xe2\\xe8\\x100\\x13\\xa7U\\xb7\\x8f\\x0e1\\xca\\xdcW\\xb8U\\xd7\\x8d\\x0e\\x003\\
xf1\\xe5f\\\\\\xb6\\xa5p\\xab\\xae\\x1d\\x1d\\x00fb\\xf6\\xc7\\x9a\\xc2\\xb5\\xc2\\x85e\\xf9\\xd4\\xe8\\x00\\xa3)\\\\\\xbfuaYf\\x7f\\xac)\\xdc\\xbaft\\x00\\x98\\x89\\xd9\\x
afp]\\xa5P\\xc74\\xdd\\xdf}\\xc2\\xe8 \\xb0\\xe1\\x9eY\\xdd2:\\xc4HV\\xb8\\xf5P\\xf5\\xf1\\xd1!`\\xc3]\\xdf\\xcc\\xcb\\xb6\\x14\\xeec\\xae\\x1a\\x1d\\x006\\xdcGF\\x07X\\x05
\\nw\\xf2\\xd1\\xd1\\x01`\\xc3)\\xdc\\x14\\xeec\\xae\\x1c\\x1d\\x006\\x9c\\xbf\"s\\xd2\\xec1\\xfb\\x9a\\x9e\\x1c\\xf6\\xcc\\xd1A`\\x03=\\xd8tK\\xef\\xec\\xdf!h\\x85;y\\xb4\
\xfa\\xe0\\xe8\\x10\\xb0\\xa1>\\x9c\\xb2\\xad\\x14\\xee\\xd7\\xfb\\xe0\\xe8\\x00\\xb0\\xa1>0:\\xc0\\xaaP\\xb8\\x8f\\xfb\\xe0\\xe8\\x00\\xb0\\xa1\\xde?:\\xc0\\xaa\\xb0\\x87\
\xbb\\xbf\\x9b\\xaag\\x8f\\x0e\\x01\\x1b\\xe4\\xde\\xa6\\xfd\\xdb\\x07G\\x07Y\\x05V\\xb8\\xfb{\\xcf\\xe8\\x00\\xb0a>\\x90\\xb2\\xfd\\xff\\x14\\xee\\xfe\\xde5:\\x00l\\x98\\x
ff6:\\xc0*\\xb1\\xa5\\xb0\\xbf\\xe3\\xab[\\xb7\\xbe\\x02G\\xe6\\x91\\xea9M\\x0f\\x1e\\'+\\xdc\\'\\xba\\xafz\\xef\\xe8\\x10\\xb0!>\\x9c\\xb2\\xdd\\x8f\\xc2}\\xb2\\xdf\\x19\\
x1d\\x006\\x84\\xed\\x84\\'\\xb0\\xa5\\xf0dOoz\\xb3\\xe8\\xb1\\xa3\\x83\\xc0\\x1a{\\xb4:\\xa7\\xfa\\xb3\\xd1AV\\x89\\x15\\xee\\x93}\\xa5\\xfa\\xbd\\xd1!`\\xcd}(e\\xfb$\\n\\
xf7\\xc0~}t\\x00Xs\\xffit\\x80UdK\\xe1\\xc0\\x9e\\xda\\xb4\\xd9\\x7f\\xf2\\xe8 \\xb0\\x86\\x1e\\xa8\\xce\\xacn\\x1b\\x1dd\\xd5X\\xe1\\x1e\\xd8\\xfd\\xd5o\\x8d\\x0e\\x01k\\x
ea\\xdd)\\xdb\\x03R\\xb8\\x07\\xf7k\\xa3\\x03\\xc0\\x9az\\xfb\\xe8\\x00\\xab\\xca\\x96\\xc2\\xa1\\xfd\\xef\\xea\\xa2\\xd1!`\\x8d\\xfcYun\\xd3M\\x0f<\\x81\\x15\\xee\\xa1]>:\
\x00\\xac\\x99_N\\xd9\\x1e\\x94\\x15\\xee\\xa1\\x9dX}\\xa1:ut\\x10X\\x03\\xf7UgU_\\x1d\\x1ddUY\\xe1\\x1e\\xda\\xdd\\xd5\\x7f\\x1c\\x1d\\x02\\xd6\\xc4\\x7fN\\xd9\\x1e\\x92\\
x15\\xee\\xe1\\x9d]}\\xba:zt\\x10Xa\\x8fV/\\xa9>>:\\xc8*\\xb3\\xc2=\\xbc\\xeb\\xaaw\\x8c\\x0e\\x01+\\xee\\xdd)\\xdb\\xc3\\xb2\\xc2\\xdd\\x9e\\x177]\\xb1\\xe0\\xfb\\x05\\x07
\\xf6\\xed\\xd5\\x95\\xa3C\\xac:+\\xdc\\xed\\xf9D\\x1eN\\x0e\\x07\\xf3\\xbe\\x94\\xed\\xb6X\\xb1m\\xdf\\xc5\\xf9\\xa1\\x82\\x03yM^\\x14\\xb9-V\\xb8\\xdb\\xf7\\xbf\\xf2\\x14
1x\\xa2\\xff\\x99\\xb2\\xdd6+\\xdc\\x9dyIuu~QAMW&|G\\xfe\\xf2\\xdb6\\xc5\\xb13\\xd74]k\\x08\\xd4o\\xa7lw\\xc4\\nw\\xe7\\x9e_][\\x1d7:\\x08\\x0c\\xf4P\\xf5\\xcdM\\xc7\\x02\\
xdbd\\x85\\xbbs\\xd7Wo\\x19\\x1d\\x02\\x06{[\\xcav\\xc7\\xacpw\\xe7\\xb4\\xa6\\x1f\\xb6g\\x8c\\x0e\\x02\\x03\\xdcZ\\x9d\\xdf\\xf4:*v\\xc0\\nwwn\\xab~ft\\x08\\x18\\xe4\\x1f\
\xa7lw\\xc5\\nw\\xf7\\xf6UWT\\xaf\\x18\\x1d\\x04\\x96\\xe8\\xaa\\xea\\x92<\\x82qW\\x14\\xee\\x91yq\\xf5\\xd1\\xea\\x98\\xd1A`\\t\\x1ei*\\xdb\\xabF\\x07YW\\x9e\\x80udnnz\\xd
1\\xe4w\\x8e\\x0e\\x02K\\xf0\\xd6\\xeaWG\\x87XgV\\xb8G\\xee\\x84\\xa6\\xebs\\xcf\\x19\\x1d\\x04\\x16\\xe8\\xffV\\xdf\\xd2\\xf4\\x8chv\\xc9I\\xb3#wo\\xf5\\xa6\\xea\\xe1\\xd1
A`A\\x1e\\xad\\xfeV\\xca\\xf6\\x88\\xd9R\\xd8\\x1b_lZ\\xe9:\\x81\\xc6&\\xba\\xbc\\xe9]e\\x1c![\\n{\\xe7\\xb8\\xa6\\x93\\t\\xdf<:\\x08\\xec\\xa1\\xeb\\x9a\\x9e!r\\xcf\\xe8 \
\x9b\\xc0\\x96\\xc2\\xdey\\xa0zcu\\xff\\xe8 \\xb0G\\x1e\\xac\\xfeZ\\xcav\\xcf\\xd8R\\xd8[_jz\\x89\\xde\\xf7\\x8d\\x0e\\x02{\\xe0\\xcd\\xd5;G\\x87\\xd8$\\nw\\xef]\\xd5t\\xdb
\\xa3\\xad\\x05\\xd6\\xd9\\xbb\\xaa\\x9f\\x1c\\x1db\\xd3\\xd8\\xc3]\\x8c\\x93\\xab\\x8fT\\xe7\\x8e\\x0e\\x02\\xbb\\xf0\\xf9\\xea\\xa5y\\xe5\\xf9\\x9e\\xb3\\x87\\xbb\\x18wV?
\\xd8t\\xc9\\x18\\xac\\x93\\xfb\\xaa\\x1fH\\xd9.\\x84\\xc2]\\x9ck\\xaa\\x1fn\\xba\\x86\\x11\\xd6\\xc5\\x8f6\\xbdN\\x8a\\x05\\xb0\\x87\\xbbX\\x9f\\xdc\\xfaz\\xe9\\xc8\\x10\\
xb0M\\xff\\xb6\\xfa\\xf9\\xd1!6\\x99\\xc2]\\xbc+r\\x12\\x8d\\xd5\\xf7\\x9e\\xeaG\\xf2\\x17\\xd9B9i\\xb6\\x1c\\'4\\xbd\\xd9\\xf4\\x92\\xd1A\\xe0\\x00>Q\\xbd\\xb2\\xbact\\x90
M\\xa7p\\x97\\xe7\\x19\\xd5\\x87\\xaa\\xb3G\\x07\\x81\\xaf\\xf3\\xd9\\xeaUM\\xb7\\xa7\\xb3`\\nw\\xb9\\x9e_\\xfdQu\\xd6\\xe8 P\\xdd\\xd2\\xf4h\\xd1\\xebF\\x07\\x99\\x0bW),\\
xd7\\xf5\\xd5\\xf7V\\xb7\\x8f\\x0e\\xc2\\xec\\xdd[\\xbd6e\\xbbT\\nw\\xf9>Q\\xfd\\xa5\\xdc\\x9f\\xce8\\xf7V\\xaf\\xaf\\xae\\x1c\\x1ddn\\x14\\xee\\x18WV\\xdf\\x93\\xe7\\x8b\\
xb2|\\xf7U\\xdf_\\xbdwt\\x909\\xb2\\x87;\\xd6+\\xaa\\xffQ\\x9d4:\\x08\\xb3\\xf0@\\xd3\\xca\\xf6wG\\x07\\x81Q\\xfe\\\\\\xd3\\xe58\\x8f\\x1a\\xb3\\xc0\\xb9\\xbf\\xe9\\xaf*\\x
98\\xbdo\\xafnm\\xfcAi6s\\xee\\xac\\xfe|\\x0cgKau\\\\\\xd0\\xb4\\xbd\\xf0\\xfc\\xd1A\\xd8(77]\\x19s\\xf5\\xe8 (\\xdcU\\xf3\\xdc\\xa6\\xfd5\\xb7\\x01\\xb3\\x17>W}w\\xf5\\x99
\\xc19\\xd8\\xe2*\\x85\\xd5rC\\xd3]?W\\x8c\\x0e\\xc2\\xda\\xbb\\xa6\\xe9\\xfc\\x80\\xb2\\x85\\xc38\\xaez{\\xe3\\xf7\\xfe\\xccz\\xceoW\\'\\x06\\xec\\xc8OV\\x0f5\\xfe\\x006\\
xeb1\\x8fT?\\x9b\\xadB\\xd8\\xb5\\xbf\\xd8\\xf4\\xf4\\xfd\\xd1\\x07\\xb3Y\\xed\\xb9\\xaf\\xfa\\xa1\\x80#vv\\xf5\\xb1\\xc6\\x1f\\xd4f5\\xe73\\xd5K\\x02\\xf6\\xccS\\xab\\xb74
\\xfe\\xe06\\xab5\\xefhzi)\\xb0\\x00\\x7f\\xb5\\xba\\xad\\xf1\\x07\\xba\\x19;\\xf7U\\x7f\\'`\\xe1^X\\xfdq\\xe3\\x0fz3f\\xae\\xa9.\\nX\\x9a\\xa3\\xaa77=jot\\x01\\x98\\xe5\\x
cc\\xd7\\x9a\\xaeBxJ\\xc0\\x10\\xe75\\xbd\\xbagt\\x19\\x98\\xc5\\xce\\xa7\\xf2N<X\\tGW?U\\xdd\\xd5\\xf8b0{;\\x0fT\\xff\\xbc:>`\\xa5\\x9cU\\xfd\\x97\\xc6\\x97\\x84\\xd9\\x9b
youn\\xc0J\\xfb\\xae\\xea\\xd3\\x8d/\\x0c\\xb3\\xbb\\xb9\\xb1\\xfa\\xc1\\'}\\xaa\\xc0\\xcazJ\\xd36\\xc3-\\x8d/\\x10\\xb3\\xbd\\xb9\\xab\\xfa\\xa7y\\x0e\\x02\\xac\\xadS\\x9b
\\xcel\\xbb\\x9aau\\xe7kM7\\xb5<\\xfb \\x9f!\\xb0f\\xce\\xac\\xfe}\\xf5`\\xe3\\x0b\\xc6L\\xf3p\\xd3\\x9e\\xfb9\\x87\\xf8\\xdc\\x805\\xf6\\xbc\\xea\\xf2\\xacxG\\xce\\x83M\\x
8f\\xdf<\\xef\\xd0\\x1f\\x15\\xb0)\\x9eU\\xfd\\\\\\xd3\\xfb\\xaeF\\x17\\xd0\\\\\\xe6\\xbe\\xea\\xad\\xd5\\x0b\\x0e\\xff\\xf1\\x00\\x9b\\xe8\\xd4\\xea\\'\\x9a\\x9e85\\xba\\x
906u\\xae\\xaf\\xfeQ\\xf5\\x8cm~&\\xc0\\x86;\\xaa\\xe9\\xfdW\\xefn\\xda[\\x1c]R\\xeb>\\x8fT\\x7fP\\xfd\\xe5\\xa6\\x1bS\\x00\\x0e\\xe8\\x05\\xd5?\\xc9\\xaaw7\\xf3\\xb9\\xa6;
\\xc3\\xce\\xdf\\xe1\\xf7\\x1c\\xa0\\xefh\\xbad\\xe9\\xd6\\xc6\\x97\\xd9\\xaa\\xce\\xedMW\\x80\\xbc*\\xaf\\xb7\\x01\\xf6\\xc0\\xb1Mw\\xb0]^}\\xbe\\xf1%7z\\xbe\\xd0t\\x02\\x
ec\\xbb\\xf3\\xf4.\\xb6\\xc9ocvc_\\xf5\\xb2\\xea\\xb2\\xa6w\\xae\\xbd\\xbc:fh\\xa2\\xc5{\\xa8\\xba\\xba\\xfa\\xfd\\xea\\xbfW\\x1fm*^\\xd86\\x85\\xcb^8\\xb9\\xe9\\xcf\\xe9Wo
\\xcd\\x8b\\x9bN\\xc2\\xad\\xb3\\x87\\x9bJ\\xf5\\x83[\\xf3\\x87M\\xb7\\xde\\xc2\\xae)\\\\\\x16\\xe1\\xa4\\xea[\\xb7\\xe6\\xdb\\xb6\\xe6\\x05#\\x03\\x1d\\xc6#\\xd5\\xb5M\\x0
5{\\xf5\\xd6|,\\x05\\xcb\\x1eS\\xb8,\\xcbiM\\x8f\\x1a\\xbc\\xa0\\xe9\\x0e\\xab\\xf3\\x9a\\xce\\xe4?\\xaf:aI\\x19\\xee\\xaa\\xfe\\xf4\\xeb\\xe6\\xda\\xa6+1>Y\\xdd\\xbd\\xa4\
\x0c\\xcc\\x98\\xc2e\\x15\\x9c\\xd2\\xf4,\\xdf\\xe76=\\xf3\\xe1\\xd9M\\xdb\\x14\\'=\\xe1\\xeb\\x13\\x1d\\xd7\\xb4\\xb7z_uOu\\xc7\\xd6\\xbf\\xef\\xaen\\xae\\xbe\\\\\\xdd\\xb
0\\xf5\\xef\\x1b\\x9b\\xee\\xaa\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\
\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x
00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00
\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00`\\x85\\xfd?\\xf2\\xf2[\\xa1\\x1c\\xbeY\\x10\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x
00IEND\\xaeB`\\x82'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve it using the code snippet below based on your requirement.

If the base64encoding is a string:

```
image_string = "data:image/{{ img_format }};base64,{{ encode_image }}"

import base64

file_format = image_string.split(';')[0].split('/')[1]
image_data = image_string.split('base64,')[1]

with open("<YOUR_FILE_NAME>" + "." + file_format, "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(bytes(image_data, "utf-8")))
```

If the base64encoding is a bytes (as mentioned in Template - View2):

```
context = {
     'encode_image': encode_image,
     'img_format': img_format,
}

import base64
with open("<YOUR_FILE_NAME>" + '.' + img_format, "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(context['encode_image']))
```

Comment: The image_data (img) is a string containing the data of the image. so it hasn't been base64encoded yet. what i'm trying to do is convert the string of the image data back into (image data/python image object). so i can then base64encode it.

Comment: But since you already have the image as a string, you can anyways split the string by 'base64,' (as done in my answer above) and get the base64encoding for that image.

Comment: I get a 'list index out of range' on the file_format.

Comment: Can you please help me with the image_string. Just do a print(image_string) and post the output.

Comment: sorry its a bit long.

Comment: Ohh, it seems like a stream inside a string. I am not really sure how you ended up there. Ideally, you should either have one of the types for the image_string. But, the below code should help you out get the base64 encoded string for the image:

`>>> import base64                 >>> image_string = image_string[2:-1]  # Stripping off the single quotes inside the string and the 'b' of the bytes object.                  >>> sanitized_string = image_string.encode('base64').replace('\n', '')                  
  >>> your_base64_string = base64.b64encode(bytes(sanitized_string, 'utf-8'))`

Comment: Hey im getting a error: 'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs, on the line sanitized_string = image_string.encode('base64').replace('\n', '')

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I ended up providing the wrong code. Try this. `>>> import base64 >>> your_base64_string = base64.b64encode(bytes(image_string[2:-1], 'utf-8'))`

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, but the image isn't showing up. also when i decode the base64 back into image data and try to open it the error: 'cannot identify image file' =).

Comment: These conversions can be a bit of a mystery sometimes. Just look for different ways to convert an image file to base64 encoding and vice-versa for python. Hope that helps.